# type 'Future<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int' with Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I have a Stateful Class that build a grid if Items.
This items are retrieved by an HTTP call to an external server.

I am Using PagewiseGridView (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_pagewise) to create my grid.

PagewiseGridView has a parameter called totalCount that is an INT, and it works perfectly when I get the totals from a Future because I've set an INT var inside initstate() to change the value after returning the Future.

The real problem is when I do a search on my external server.
For the search I am building a class: ShowSearch extends SearchDelegate and Search delegate has widget called buildResult that will show the results that I get from my external call.

I am also using PagewiseGridView to build my results layout.

Here's the code:

```
@override
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement buildResults
  return PagewiseGridView(
    pageSize: 10,
    totalCount: BackendService.getSearchTotals(query),
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
    //childAspectRatio: 0.802,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
    pageFuture: (pageIndex){
      return BackendService.getSearchItems(pageIndex, query);
    },
  );
}
```

"totalCount: BackendService.getSearchTotals(query)" returns a Future, so it does not work because it requires an INT (totalCount: 100, works).

How can I solve this?

FULL CLASS (Different Method):

```
class ShowSearch extends SearchDelegate<BackendService> {
  Color _mainColor = const Color(0xFFCA0813);
  int _searchTotalCounter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //super.initState();
    getSearchTotalCounter();
  }

  void getSearchTotalCounter() async {
    _searchTotalCounter = await getSearchTotals(query);

    //setState(() {});
  }

  Future<int> getSearchTotals(query) async {
    var myRes = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("https://www.mydomain.io/wp-json/test/v1/stats/search/?s=$query"), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var myResBody = json.decode(myRes.body);

    return myResBody["count_total"];
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildActions
    return [IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      onPressed: (){
        query = "";
      }
    )];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildLeading
    return IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: (){
      close(context, null);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildSuggestions
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Center(
              child: Text(query)
          )
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement buildResults
    return PagewiseGridView(
        pageSize: 10,
        totalCount: _searchTotalCounter,
        //totalCount: 20 //IT WORKS!
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
        //childAspectRatio: 0.802,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
        pageFuture: (pageIndex){
          return BackendService.getSearchItems(pageIndex, query);
        },
    );
  }
}
```

I've commented super.initState() and setState() because are giving an error (error: The method 'initState' isn't defined in a superclass of 'SearchDelegate'.) and (error: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'ShowSearch'.).

```
https://www.mydomain.io/wp-json/test/v1/stats/search/?s=$query
```

returns

```
{"status":"ok","total":10,"count_total":502,"pages":51,"query":"beans"}
```

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder` for `BackendService.getSearchTotals(query)` and then build `PagewiseGridView` in this builder.

Comment: You can also call `BackendService.getSearchTotals(query)` in `initState` and store the result in a field for later use in `build`, but you can't use `await` in `initState` to get the value out of the `Future` so you would need to move the call to `BackendService.getSearchTotals(query)` to another method where you use `async`/`await` that you then call from `initState`. That sounds a bit cumbersome, but if the logic to get the value is a bit more complex than a single function call, then it might make sense.

Comment: can You please explain the last option, because I tried that way and I cannot setState inside the new method.

Comment: It would be great if you could post your code that didn't work and then we can discuss how to fix it.

Comment: You mean with the initState()?

Comment: Yes, the code that didn't work.

Comment: I've added the Full Class at the end of the question

Comment: "'initState' isn't defined in a superclass of 'SearchDelegate'" -> make a stateful widget and move your stuff there and then in `buildResults()` remove that widget. This will also fix `setState`

Comment: What widget do I have to remove?

Comment: No, create a new widget and nove the code I mentioned above to that widget.

Answer (score 1):

first you can add totalCount: count, and set count to 0 then call this getCount() method mentioned here what will happen , first BackendService.getSearchTotals(query) will be called and when it finishes it will return a future, then you can use the result
to update the count and rebuild using setState ,
ps:you can show a circular loader while the getCount is working.

```
Future getCount() async {
       //here you can call the function and handle the output(return value) as result
           BackendService.getSearchTotals(query).then((result) {
               // print(result);
               setState(() {
                  //handle your result here and update the count.
                  //update build here.
               });
          }).catchError(handleError);//you can call handleError method show an alert or to try again
     }
```